# Oracle sql to_date on timestamp + interval. What is more optimal

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, timestamp

I was curious what is more optimal/efficient syntax of oracle SQL query containing comparison statement:

```
WHERE time_stamp + INTERVAL '+1' HOUR
        BETWEEN to_date('13-08-2016 17:02', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
            AND to_date('21-11-2016 16:02', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

or

```
WHERE time_stamp
        BETWEEN to_date('13-08-2016 17:02', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') - INTERVAL '+1' HOUR
            AND to_date('21-11-2016 16:02', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') - INTERVAL '+1' HOUR
```

Will the sql parsers do the optimisation job?

Answer (score 2):

I would advise writing these as:

```
WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2016-08-13 17:02:00' - INTERVAL '1' HOUR AND 
                         TIMESTAMP '2016-11-21 16:02:00' - INTERVAL '1' HOUR
```

The use of `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` for ISO-formatted constants just keeps the code cleaner (in my opinion).

Also, having the date arithmetic on the "constants" makes it easier for the optimizer to use an index, if an appropriate one is available.

Comment: "*keeps the code cleaner*" - in my opinion as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether you have an index on that time_stamp column. 
If you have an index, it's best not to do any expressions or functions on that column.
For that reason, if the column has an index, the second query will perform better.